# Why my figure isn't at top of the text?

Tags: graphics, positioning, subfloats, subcaption

I'm new in LaTeX and I'm trying to use the environments `\subfigure` and `\subcaption`. The two images inside the main image are OK, but the image containing the other two isn't in the correct position. And, in the code, when I write some text at the bottom of the figure, then it appears up, and the figure in the middle of the next page. I share with you this image so you can see my situation:

Page 9:

[image]

Page 10:

[image]

and the code:

```
  La arquitectura de UFSBI se muestra en la figura
  \ref{fig:disenoUFSBI}.
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=5cm]{Architecture}
    \centering
    \caption{Architecture of UFSBI}
    \label{fig:architecture}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=5cm, right]{Diagram}
    \centering
    \caption{Module Inter-connection diagram}
    \label{fig:interconnectionUSBF}
  \end{subfigure}
\caption{UFSBI Design}
\label{fig:disenoUFSBI}
\end{figure}
Afeter aa sfdasdf asdfas dfasd fasdfas df.as .fas.d f.asd.fa.sd.f .sad.f .asd.f.a sd.f.a sd.f. as.df. as.df. as.
```

Can someone help me? Thanks from before.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/69818)  If your problem is that the contents of the `figure` environment float to some other place, that is precisely the purpose of a “floating” environment like `figure`.  Could you further clarify the issue, and include a complete code sample (from `\documentclass{...}` to `\end{document}`) that reproduces it?

Comment: Inside a `subfigure` environment you're supposed to use `\caption` not `\subcaption`, I think.

Comment: The problem is that the all text that i write at the bottom of the image, appears at the top, the image is floating in the middle of the page, and that's not my purpose.

Comment: It was wrong, but the "/subcaptions" doesn't fix my problem

Comment: `figure` environments are floating environments (i.e. they can move around so you avoid bad pagebreaks), that's the point of them. I guess http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text will solve your problem?

Comment: Use `\begin{figure}[t]`? The normal options are `[t]`, `[b]`, and `[h]`, for `top`, `bottom`, and `here`, though you shouldn't use `h` by itself....

Comment: @jon The red arrow suggests the OP wants not a float at all, doesn't it? In which case, the existing suggestions to not use `figure` are probably what is wanted here.

Comment: @cfr -- well, it sure looks that way now that the question has been edited. But before there was no picture and the title of the question does not suggest 'at the top of some arbitrary chunk of text'..!